# Import image resource after imagejpeg

Tags: php, fluid, typo3-flow

I am trying to import a resource which I persisted via imagejpeg...

```
$imageFileName = "tmp_image_path.jpg"; 
imagejpeg($thumb, $imageFileName); 
$newResource = $this->resourceManager->importResource($imageFileName);
$image = new \TYPO3\Media\Domain\Model\Image($newResource);
$project->setPicture($image);
$this->projectRepository->update($project);
$resourceUri = $this->resourceManager->getPublicPersistentResourceUri($project->getPicture()->getResource());
```

But doing `echo 'Resized: <img src="' .$resourceUri. '"/>';`

Returns: image path not found

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$newResource = $this->resourceManager->importResource($imageFileName);
```

this imports only resource by path not with filename only.
so

```
$imageFileName = "tmp_image_path.jpg";
```

should be written as :

```
$imageFileName = "resource://<Package.Name>/Public/tmp_image_path.jpg";
```

Pls try this, should work with resource path